# Should I abstract technical details from Kafka ETL?

Tags: database, oracle, apache-kafka, integration, etl

What’s best practice to attach an ERP (or any other “standard software” that might come with complicated, technical data models) as a source to a kafka system?

Would you recommend to hide these technical details using views in that source database? Not sure, if a view can “trigger” the replication inside a JDBC source connector for oracle.

Another way I can think of is “joining” all these tables in kafka using its Stream API. This way, the source database system is not used to perform “ETL joins”.

Comment: Sorry, but this questions falls right in the middle of a class of questions that are NOT appropriate for this web site. *4.Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: Besides which, the whole Kafka landscape is too new for there to be any "best practice". There's only experimentation

Comment: I'm not asking for a book of that author with the same Name. I just wonder if People stream tables directly ir if they build views. If that's an inpropriate use your Website, please delete the question.

Comment: You can do it either way. Some people do joins in Kafka Streams, some do it in the source database, some do it in the target/sink database(s). All depends on the use case and what else you want to do with the data in Kafka

Comment: @roger, what mathguy is saying is that questions like this tend to generate lots of opinionated answers rather than pure technical answers which makes them better asked on Quora than Stack Overflow. SO prefers to cultivate a less opinionated dialogue. That makes some architecture questions difficult but it also gets rid of all the "vim is better than emacs" wars

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating (assuming one doesn't exist already) a Kafka Connect source connector for you ERP software. In it, try hiding the complexity of dealing with the technicalities of the ERP. You can also do some simple stateless conversions to abstract away from the specifics of the ERP model into your domain model. My experience tells me this won't be sufficient and the output will still be somewhat bound to the source model if it's complicated. Please remember to partition the data in a way that makes sense in your domain.

Next, once you have the data in kafka and partitioned well, you can do further processing in Kafka Streams. These have fault-tolerant (with Kafka v0.11 even transactional) stateful processing capabilities and allow doing joins between topics easily.